# Text Input layout hint is overlapped with the outlined box

Tags: android, xml, android-textinputlayout

my text input layout's hint text seems overlapped[image]

how can I move the hint text to little right of the outline.

my xml :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tilAddress"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvBillingText">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tilAddress1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:hint="Address1 *"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvBillingText"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>`
```

any hep is appreciated . thanks

**Edit**

By removing the margin , i could fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the layout_margin from Edittext and it could solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the hint on the `TextInputLayout` instead of the EditText? I think it's also recommended to replace the `EditText` with a `TextInputEditText` like in the following example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/form_username">

     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: hi , I tried TextInputEditText too.. but it looks same .